# Уникальные (первые) значения списка по категории

Tags: jquery

У меня есть список, я получаю значения, но мне нужно получить только первые значения из каждой категории, как мне написать условие в JQuery, чтобы в консоль выходили значения: **Title1 == Split, Title4 == Aproved, Title7 == None**?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
var data = [{
    "Title": "Title1",
    "Category": "Split"
}, {
    "Title": "Title2",
    "Category": "Split"
}, {
    "Title": "Title3",
    "Category": "Split"
}, {
    "Title": "Title4",
    "Category": "Aproved"
}, {
    "Title": "Title5",
    "Category": "Aproved"
}, {
    "Title": "Title6",
    "Category": "Aproved"
}, {
    "Title": "Title7",
    "Category": "None"
}, {
    "Title": "Title8",
    "Category": "None"
}, {
    "Title": "Title9",
    "Category": "None"
}, {
    "Title": "Title10",
    "Category": "None"
}];
```

Comment: вместо картинки лучше приведите фрагмент верстки. И напишите, этот перечень категорий статичен, или в принципе может быть произвольным?

Comment: @teran список меняется, категории могут быть другими, но суть та же. Фрагмент верстки зачем? Я же не стили правлю мне нужна логика? в вопрос, добавлю код.

Comment: Если условие это не селектор jquery то мб верстка и не нужна. Логика тут проста как валенок, цикл по элементам, как только категория сменилась - добаляем элемент  к результату.

Comment: @teran вынес в JSON.

Comment: @Lion, нужно определять выбранные? Если да, то в какой момент? Когда они выбраны пользователем или изначально? И как вообще выглядит список? `<select>`'ом или на `<div>`'ах?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант решения с `reduce` для вашего json

```js
var data = [{"Title":"Title1","Category":"Split"},{"Title":"Title2","Category":"Split"},{"Title":"Title3","Category":"Split"},{"Title":"Title4","Category":"Aproved"},{"Title":"Title5","Category":"Aproved"},{"Title":"Title6","Category":"Aproved"},{"Title":"Title7","Category":"None"},{"Title":"Title8","Category":"None"},{"Title":"Title9","Category":"None"},{"Title":"Title10","Category":"None"}];

var result = data.reduce( (r, v) => { 
                      var c = v.Category;
                      if( !(c in r)) r[c]  = v.Title;
                      return r;
                  }, {});
                             
console.log(result)                             ;
```

Comment: Респект, спасибо, подробно изучу reduce!